How to add extra vertices in the form of a semicircle to the model
I need to add semicircle vertices to my model (photo 1) to make it looks like in the photo 2 and 3. but i don't know how to do this. I've tried to learn this by myself, but I failed. Can someone help me?




hello, do you plan to use a Subdivision Surface modifier? In that case you can cut off your semi-circle with only several vertices and it will be rounded by the modifier

@moonboots thx for your answer! I added a new photo to give you a deeper look to my problem. I wanna add vertices not only on models edges, but in any place I want. I've tried to use knife tool to make vertices on the face instead of the edge, but I don't get how was made this perfectly rounded semi-circle in the photo number 3.

You can use the Knife Project tool, create another object that is the semi-circle mesh, now back to Object mode, select your main object, switch it to Edit mode, Ctrl left click on the semi-circle object, then top menu > Mesh > Knife Project

@moonboots thank you! You've helped me a lot!!!

To draw the edge loop you show in picture 3, you can use the Knife Project tool: Create another object that is the semi-circle mesh, now back to Object mode, select your main object, switch it to Edit mode, CtrlLMB on the semi-circle object, then top menu > Mesh > Knife Project. The Cut Through option is available in the Operator Box:

